# scp no such file or directory exists, but the file does exist

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

First, I want to say I am sorry if this is posted in the wrong section. this is my first post here, and this is the first time I'm making an account.

What I am trying to do is copy a file from a remote server to my local machine. So I found out through google you do it with **scp**.

I'm ssh-ing into the server, and do:

`scp -P 8888 username@websitename:public_html/index.html/Documents/newfolder`

but I get this error:

`scp: /public_html/index.html: No such file or directory`

But, on the remote server, if I do  **cd public_html** and then ls, i can see the file there. The same thing happens if I log out of ssh and do it from a normal terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `username`'s home on the remote machine, does `/etc/passwd` think it's the same as what you think it is?  Note how your `scp` invocation uses `websitename:public_html/index.html` (which implies ~ as the starting point), but the error says `/public_html/index.html` (which suggests that *public_html* lies in the root directory...

Comment: indeed, the full path to the file is /home2/username/public_html/index.html. i changed that, so now we have:

`scp -P 8888 username@websitename:/home2/username/public_html/index.html/ /home/localname/Documents/newfolder`

but now it says:

**/home/localname/Documents/newfolder: No such file or directory**

what's the reason? the folder is there on the local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the path you want is without the index.html.  Because that is just a file, its not a folder.  And you are not browsing with a browser.

`scp -P 8888 username@websitename:public_html/Documents/newfolder`

Comment: you were kinda right. not the full explanation, but sent me into the right direction. for whatever reason using -r will make it work, even if i copy the whole folder, even if i copy only the index.html file.

i have no idea why adding -r option worked, because its definition is "copies the entire directory recursively", even though it works just fine if i copy just the index.html file.

tldr: -r made it work, i do not understand why at all.

Comment: -r makes no difference for me.